# Consulta SQL en Laravel - un select dentro de otro select con max

Tags: sql, laravel

estoy que desarrollo un pequeño sistema en Laravel y tengo un problema es que tengo una consulta sql que la quiero hacer en Laravel pero la noto un poco complicado:

-Consulta sql:

```
select HistoriaPersona.NroHistoria as NumeroHistoria, Persona.Nombre, Servicios.Nombre as Servicios
from HistoriaPersona
JOIN Persona ON HistoriaPersona.IdPersona = Persona.IdPersona
JOIN Servicios on HistoriaPersona.IdServicio = Servicios.IdServicio
where HistoriaPersona.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM HistoriaPersona JOIN Persona ON HistoriaPersona.IdPersona = Persona.IdPersona WHERE HistoriaPersona.Salida = 1 and HistoriaPersona.Retorno IS NULL and HistoriaPersona.NroHistoria=750665)
```

> HistoriaPersona.NroHistoria=750665 => Aqui sera el valor que ingrese lo demas es por defecto.

-Consulta en sql en LARAVEL (Mi avance):

```
$text = $request->text;
        $data = HistoriaPersona::join('Persona', 'HistoriaPersona.IdPersona', 'Persona.IdPersona')
                                            ->join('Servicios', 'HistoriaPersona.IdServicio', 'Servicios.IdServicio')
                                            ->select('HistoriaPersona.NroHistoria AS NumeroHistoria',
                                                    'Persona.Nombre AS Nombre',
                                                    'Servicios.Nombre AS Servicios')
                                            ->where('HistoriaPersona.ID', '=', '(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM HistoriaPersona JOIN Persona ON HistoriaPersona.IdPersona = Persona.IdPersona WHERE HistoriaPersona.Salida = 1 and HistoriaPersona.Retorno IS NULL and HistoriaPersona.NroHistoria='.$text.')')
                                            ->get();
```

Sé que está mal, pero no se como seria la solución.

Comment: Hace una consulta por fuera para obtener el max y luego lo utilizas en tu where. Será lo mas facil. Puedes hacerlo con un closure pero es lo mismo. Saludos!